# Getting "GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend. Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications." error in Anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting this error in my Anaconda just after i install opencv in it. I know its a repeated question in StackOverflow but i tried all the fixes that are previously given here and nothing changes.

I tried this [fix](https://github.com/conda-forge/glib-feedstock/issues/19) it solves the problem but not permanently. It works only when i run the command on terminal it works fine then but as soon after i close the terminal and starts it again and run program again error starts to appear again. Is there any permanent solution??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export GIO_EXTRA_MODULES=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/
```